# Tricky database query

Tags: foxpro

There DBMS Foxpro 2.6 for DOS.
Suppose it has a film library database consisting of two tables  FILM and COPY_MOV.
Table FILM Soto of the following columns
id_film, title, director, year
Table COPY_MOV Soto of the following columns:
id_cpy, id_film, type_media, format

Both tables are indexed on the field: id_film, id_copy.

We need to find all the movies that were not released copies. I wrote the following query SQL:

```
select * from FILM where ID_FILM not in (select ID_FILM from COPY_MOV)
```

It will be possible to implement the same, only the operator SEEK foxpro?

Comment: Assuming you're using FoxPro 2.6 to query, it doesn't support the WHERE ... IN clause.

Comment: That's not correct, Alan. WHERE ... IN was supported from the time SELECT was added to FoxPro (that is, FoxPro 2.0).

Comment: Why not just use the query? Any other approach requires a lot more code.

Comment: LOL in that case it may be that I didn't realise it was there until VFP7.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Seek() function in your Where filter:

```
CREATE CURSOR film (id_film I)
INSERT INTO film VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO film VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO film VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO film VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO film VALUES (5)
CREATE CURSOR copy_mov (id_film I)
INDEX on id_film TAG id_film
INSERT INTO copy_mov VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO copy_mov VALUES (5)

SELECT * FROM film WHERE NOT SEEK(id_film, "copy_mov")
```

If you rather want to avoid SQL `Select` entirely:

```
CREATE CURSOR result (id_film I)
SELECT film
SCAN FOR NOT SEEK(id_film, "copy_mov")
    INSERT INTO result VALUES (film.id_film)
ENDSCAN
SELECT result
BROWSE
```

Or perhaps you just want to `Browse For`

```
SELECT film
BROWSE FOR NOT SEEK(id_film, "copy_mov")
```